# MySQL DATETIME shows correct date, but incorrect time (always midnight) in one table but not in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin

I am using MySQL's `DATETIME` to set the date and time in two different tables in a database (with PHP). One of these instances is in the `users` table and logs the time the person signs up for an account and when they last logged in. The other usage is in a separate `messages` table (within the same database) that logs when a user sends a message to another user.

Although the MySQL `DATETIME` code is the same in each table, on the `messages` table it records the date, but the time the message was sent is always exactly midnight e.g. `2021-12-06 00:00:00`

In PHPmyAdmin I am using `DATETIME`, with no default value and not null in both tables.

The PHP prepared statements for each usage are below. As you can see, where the data and time are needed I am using the `current_date` function.

**EXAMPLE 1** `users` table (time is recorded correctly in the database). Note: some of the variables such as `fname` are from form elements. I haven't included the form code to keep the code simpler.

```
$passwordHash = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO lj_users 
            (firstname, lastname, email, username, password, 
            date_registered, last_login, active, profile_image, 
            permissions) 
        VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :username, :password, 
                current_date, current_date, 0, '', 
                'standard' )";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $passwordHash);

$stmt->execute();
```

**EXAMPLE 2** (time is NOT recorded correctly in the database)

```
$message_sql = "INSERT INTO lj_messages 
                    (message_title, message_body, dm_recipient_id, 
                    dm_sender_id, message_date) 
                VALUES (:message_title, :message_body, :dm_recipient_id, 
                        :dm_sender_id, current_date )";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($message_sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':message_title', $dm_title);
$stmt->bindParam(':message_body', $dm_body);
$stmt->bindParam(':dm_recipient_id', $dm_recipient_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':dm_sender_id', $dm_sender_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Because `current_date` is just that: a date. Why it's working in the other table, I couldn't say. If you want a datetime, use `now()` instead.

Comment: @aynber - thanks that did sort out the issue in the `messages` table. Why is `current_date` working on signup page in the users table though? I don't understand that?

Comment: Is `date_registered and last_login` a DATE type rather than a DATETIME

Comment: @RiggsFolly no it is a DATETIME type in all instances

Comment: So show us an example of `date_registered and last_login` that are not 00:00:00

Comment: Double-check `show create table \`messages\``, and see if there's a default value on those fields.

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is a screenshot. I took this earlier. I've changed all instances to `now()` https://paste.pics/594c76d2c17985d61cc78efe2b0d111a

Comment: @aynber when I run the `show create table `messages` ` query it doesn't show me all of the information in PHPMyAdmin. I can't seem to click on what it returns to view it in full. Annoying. https://paste.pics/db9a8e89845d9a346a426ff430bc1e8b

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, just click on the table definition and show that.

Comment: @aynber - i changed the view options for the table - it wasn't set to full text. This is what is showed: https://paste.pics/9da64caa42af7c3a28acae90cb4f6060

Comment: please check the table definition. Maybe the field type is DATETIME and you enter only the date. So it shows the date correctly and sets the time 00:00:00. Use now() function or pass full date-time.

Comment: Also @aynber if you want to post that comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct. At the end of the day `now()` is clearly the correct function that should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_date` returns just a date:

```
mysql> select current_date; 
+--------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                            
| current_date |                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+--------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                            
| 2021-12-07   | 
+--------------+
```

You want `now()`, which returns a datetime.

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2021-12-07 09:33:40 |
+---------------------+
```